# Replace values if two columns match in R

Tags: r

I know a little bit about R but it's been a while since I've used it. I would appreciate any help or tips on this problem. If I have two columns with numerical values (dataframe), how can I compare them so that if the first row of the two columns are equal, the values in them are replaced with the word "EQUAL" or "MATCH" or "NA", and if they are not equal, the values for those particular rows just remain the same? I don't want to create a new column with correct/incorrect values, I need the number of columns to remain the same and the data in them replaced. Would this be an if function?

I also need the very first column, which would be the Sample# column, to remain completely the same in the output.

Here's an example:

What the original file would look like (Au = column with correct data, Au_ppb = incorrect data):

```
Sample#  Au  Au_ppb  
3000    0.2  0.2    
3001    0.2  >3      
3002    0.2  0.2    
3003    0.2  0.2
3004    0.3  1.0
```

What it should look like after:

```
Sample#  Au   Au_ppb 
3000    EQUAL EQUAL  
3001    0.2   >3    
3002    EQUAL EQUAL
3003    EQUAL EQUAL
3004    0.3   1.0
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can get the indices of the equal values and replace them with our preferred text (here "EQUAL").

```
ind <- df$Au == df$Au_ppb
df[ind, c("Au", "Au_ppb")] <- "EQUAL"

#  Sample    Au Au_ppb
#1   3000 EQUAL  EQUAL
#2   3001   0.2     >3
#3   3002 EQUAL  EQUAL
#4   3003 EQUAL  EQUAL
#5   3004   0.3    1.0
```

Or a one-liner :

```
df[df$Au == df$Au_ppb, c("Au", "Au_ppb")] <- "EQUAL"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly!! I just wanted to add that I did get an error at first when I tried it but I was able to fix that (not because of your code, I had to use stringsAsFactors=FALSE to load my file). Thanks again! =D

Comment: How do I change this code if I want it to say "NOT EQUAL" for all others?

Answer (score 2):

```
replace(x = df,
        list = cbind(which(df$Au == df$Au_ppb),
                     rep(c(2,3), each = length(which(df$Au == df$Au_ppb)))),
        values = "EQUAL")
#  Sample.    Au Au_ppb
#1    3000 EQUAL  EQUAL
#2    3001   0.2     >3
#3    3002 EQUAL  EQUAL
#4    3003 EQUAL  EQUAL
#5    3004   0.3    1.0
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!! this code also worked well but I chose the other one because it was shorter. But this worked too, really appreciate the help!